# How to format names of menu items?

Tags: discussion, editing-help

There are many answers about tools such as IDEs that tell something like "go to that menu and press this and then choose the option something". I think these questions would benefit from a standardized approach to formatting that visually highlights the menu items.

A reason to have a special formatting for menu items is that it would indicate that names of menu items don't fit into the syntactic structure of the sentence, just like monospaced `delete` is not a verb but an operator, for example, and also one should consider *Install* a noun (a menu item) rather than a verb (an incentive to install something).

I personally prefer making the menu items *Italic → Connecting them with arrows → Whenever they are nested*. Is it appropriate? Or could it draw attention away from the post itself? Are there any existing approaches that people commit to?

Comment: Take a pic. Or do whatever works.  I usually do "foo -> bar -> baz" where foo, bar and baz are the actual labels on the menu items.

Answer (score 23):

A numbered list or bulleted list is sufficient.  You can nest items by indenting them four more spaces under a bulleted or numbered item.  I prefer that folks **bold the name** of the menu item.

Example:

- On the **File** menu, click **Edit.**

Answer (score 14):

There is always the hand drawn circle approach. I use these all the time [in my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30242045/1026459) in order to make visually obvious what I was referring to.

Here is a slightly extended example of showing interface steps using this approach.

<kbd>Print Screen</kbd>

Open paint

[image]

Paste your screenshot

[image]

Crop the section you wish to show as the next step

[image]

Draw the red circle on the highlighted area, copy the image, and then open the image dialogue in your answer

[image]

When the dialogue opens, use paste to automatically upload the clipboard image. It will show a preview that you accept to finish this step of the visual aid.

[image]

Comment: Although [traditional](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/248731), this isn't all that helpful for people using screen readers, slow internet connections, etc.!

Comment: @jonrsharpe - The image may not help people using screen readers. Usually you also accompany them with a small sentence explaining what is going on in the image though so they should still be supported. As for slow internet connections, I don't think that 400 bytes is really going to be that detrimental to page load time when compared with the overall size of the page.

Comment: There's not enough circles to explain why circles are best.

Comment: @TravisJ AOL just released they still have 2.1 million people using dial up.  It might affect them :)#

Comment: Considering that this page is going to be 200 kb to load, I doubt another .4kb will affect that load at all. Really, advocating against using images because there are still AOL users or slow connections is not that valid of an argument. Further, a 56k modem only loads 4.5kb per second, so I sincerely doubt those users are anywhere to be found here. And if they magically wait for the minute and a half to load one of these pages then I do not believe another fraction of a second will affect them.

Comment: @jonrsharpe If we didn't post images, screen reader users would miss the chance to interpret the meaning of every [enter image description here] with the power of their imagination!

Comment: Or [you can combine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22385089/960757)...

Comment: If you draw with Paint screenshots of Paint does it become Paintception?

Answer (score 6):

Simple is best. I use arrows and occasionally bolding. Nothing more needed.

Answer (score 3):

I tend to use pipes -

- Click "File | Open"

Answer (score 3):

> I personally prefer making the menu items *Italic → Connecting them with arrows → Whenever they are nested*. Is it appropriate?

Yes, totally. It is the standard approach - emphasise the menu titles somehow and connect them with something arrow-like for nested menus.

However, how you do that exactly is left to you. I've seen people using simple `>` signs for arrows or fancy unicode characters. For highlighting names, all sorts of formatting is used:

- bolded: **options** > **select…** > **title**
- italic: *options* → *select…* → *title*
- inline code: `options` -> `select…` -> `title`
- `<kbd>` tags: <kbd>options</kbd>⇒<kbd>select…</kbd>⇒<kbd>title</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

I take a good screenshot any time I cannot figure out how to explain something/ problem, times where words are not enough or are confusing.