# Markup for menu entry similar to kbd for keyboard

Tags: discussion, markdown

Is there a preferred way to document menu item selection?
The keyboard markup is useful, but I was wondering if menu/menu items had its own markup option that is recommended.

Is there a better way represent a menu item click than this?

`Select the Menu item` <kbd><kbd>Tools</kbd>
        <kbd>some menuitem</kbd></kbd>

EDIT:
Since posting the question and using better search strings I found this.
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/294550/1347784

This seems to suggest there is no "preferred" way, but a few commonly used patterns all fairly simple. Or include a screen shot rather than using **kbd** markdown.

I'm going to use this in the future:
Navigate to  *Tools*  *MenuItem*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The convention is I've mostly seen is using arrows to note menu/submenu/dialog navigation.  Often, the navigation actions are formatted to make them stand out (e.g. bold, code formatting).

For particularly confusing or complex dialogs, many users actually provide screenshots and/or animated GIFs.

Here's an excerpt from a [well-formatted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27441265/4320665) that uses a combination of arrow notation and screenshots to describe how to change a certain setting in an IDE (original emphasis preserved)

> If it's not there **open it from** 
>   **View -> Tool Windows -> Database**
>
> [image: view]
>
> - In this new popup window **choose MySQL** from the left.
>
> [image: Should look like this]

Answer (score 6):

I generally use this formatting for menus:

> Navigate to the *Tools > SQL Server > New Query...* menu

Markdown source:

```
Navigate to the *Tools > SQL Server > New Query...* menu
```

The keyboard markup might cause trouble on mobile devices if you use it like that, and I imagine it's also annoying for screen readers. Keep it simple :)

Comment: I see your point. KISS is indeed good