# Can we reduce the whitespace above question title on wide layouts?

Tags: feature-request, design

This occurs on every question I visit on SO. I haven't seen it on other network sites, that don't have the left nav bar yet. What is the cause and is it on an issue list yet?

[image]

When I narrow my window, the whitespace goes back to normal:
[image]

There are related questions like this one about the index page
[Too much whitespace at MSO's top](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/369275/too-much-whitespace-at-msos-top) but this is a different page (single question rather than index) and also the whitespace is in a different place: here it is *above* the title (rather than after the title).

Comment: We want hand drawn circles (preferably red), not ovals!

Comment: Why red? Contrast with the orange theme is poor (and red has poor contrast for some colour blind people anyway.)

Comment: @Script47 Personally I would like to see rainbow color hand drawn rectangles here.

Comment: Are you referring to this answer? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/294428/1899424

Comment: @dcorking I was joking... I'll add the */s* (*/j*?) in the future.

Comment: Please do: the exclamation mark conveyed that you were not at all in a joking mood ;D

Comment: That's strange, I can't reproduce it on my (1200px wide) display. Can you add information on how to reproduce this, such as your viewscope width, OS, browser version, and possible interfering plugins?

Comment: I believe this extra white space is appearing because you are blocking ads. Stack Overflow reserves the space above questions sometimes in order to present ads. Are you running any ad-blocking plugins in your browser? Most ad-blockers would block these ads but would not adjust the layout of the page in order to remove the extra whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

**Solved** thanks Erik von Asmuth

It was banner ads being blocked by a privacy extension - in my case DuckDuckGo Privacy Essentials.

These ads apparently only appear when the window is wide enough. In incognito mode I can see it, exactly where the mysterious white space was:

[image]